# How can I deploy an OS on a VM skipping the steps of installation?

Tags: installation, virtual-machine, virtualization, operating-systems, libvirt

If I have a virtual machine, how can I install on it an operating system skipping the installation steps?

In other words, when I choose an operating system to be installed on the VM, I want to use it immediately without bothering with the installation steps (like choosing the language, username, etc)

Also how can it be a headless VM? Meaning that I don't need the OS with a graphical user interface. I only want to use it via the terminal.

Is there anyway that I can do that?

Note: I am using KVM and libvirt.

Please help ASAP.

Thanks.

Comment: depending on the guest OS you want, your options are (1) install yourself or (2) copy an already-installed version from someone else.  option (1) can vary widely and does not always involve official installers (see eg `debootstrap`).  (option (2) has security implications.  how much do you trust the source?)

Answer (score 0):

The 'virt-install' command line tool has the ability to just setup a pre-installed disk image, instead of running an installer. Just use the '--import' command line argument. eg as root

`# virt-install --name demo \
                  --memory 512 \
                  --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/fedora-25.img,format=raw \
                  --import`

this sets up graphic display with a VNC or SPICE server by default. If you really just want a plain serial console add `--graphics none` to the args. The 'virt-install' man page details various other options you can use.

If you don't have a pre-installed disk image already, then you can use the 'virt-builder' tool to fetch one for certain OS. eg

`# virt-builder fedora-25 -o /var/lib/libvirt/images/fedora-25.img`

will download a pre-built fedora 25 image.

Comment: How can I make my own image with my own configuration?